# Excel VBA IFTTT - Advanced Filter Range Value

Tags: excel, vba, ifttt

I have a script I'm working on, I have very little actual knowledge of VBA Script except for a college class years ago...

I have this script -

```
Private Sub cmdContact_Click()
        Set DataSH = Sheet1
            DataSH.Range("O8") = Me.cboSelect.Value
            DataSH.Range("O9") = Me.txtSearch.Text
            'DataSH.Range("O9") = "*" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "*"
            DataSH.Range("B8").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
                "phonelist!Criteria"), CopyToRange:=Range("phonelist!Extract"), 
Unique:= _
                False
                ListBox1.RowSource = 
Sheet1.Range("outdata").Address(external:=True)
End Sub
```

The part I'm focusing on is this

```
        DataSH.Range("O8") = Me.cboSelect.Value
        DataSH.Range("O9") = "*" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "*"
        'DataSH.Range("O9") = Me.txtSearch.Text
```

Since the wildcards only only usable for text, I am left with 3 cbo.Select values that will not search because they're numbers.

How can I apply an IFTTT statement to the values of cboSelect?

```
DataSH.Range("O9") = "*" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "*"
```

The Values that the wildcards are needed are:
    - NAME
    - DEPARTMENT
    - TITLE
    - UNIT
    - SHIFT
    - SUPERVISOR

```
DataSH.Range("O9") = Me.txtSearch.Text
```

The values that the wildcards are NOT compatible with are:
    - EXTENSION
    - BUILDING#
    - ROOM#

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question! I figured it out with trial and error over the course of a few hours. :-)

```
If DataSH.Range("O8").Value = "NAME" Or DataSH.Range("O8").Value = "DEPARTMENT" Or DataSH.Range("O8").Value = "TITLE" Or DataSH.Range("O8").Value = "UNIT" Or DataSH.Range("O8").Value = "SHIFT" Or DataSH.Range("O8").Value = "SUPERVISOR" Then DataSH.Range("O9") = "*" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "*" Else DataSH.Range("O9") = Me.txtSearch.Text
```

Works great but if anyone wants to help me clean it up I'd appreciate it. It seems I can't get it to work unless it's all on one line?

EDIT:

Figured out how to span across multiple lines with the same if statement -

```
If DataSH.Range("O8").Value = "NAME" Or _
    DataSH.Range("O8").Value = "DEPARTMENT" Or _
        DataSH.Range("O8").Value = "TITLE" Or _
            DataSH.Range("O8").Value = "UNIT" Or _
                DataSH.Range("O8").Value = "SHIFT" Or _
            DataSH.Range("O8").Value = "SUPERVISOR" Then
        DataSH.Range("O9") = "*" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "*"
    Else
DataSH.Range("O9") = Me.txtSearch.Text
End If
```

EDIT:

Someone on another forum actually presented a better way of doing what I wanted all together. Posting here for reference:

```
Dim Ary As Variant
Ary = Array("NAME", "DEPARTMENT", "TITLE", "UNIT", "SHIFT", "SUPERVISOR")
If UBound(Filter(Ary, DataSH.Range("O8").Value, True, vbTextCompare)) >= 0 Then
    DataSH.Range("O9") = "*" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "*"
Else
    DataSH.Range("O9") = Me.txtSearch.Text
End If
```

​​​​